# Is it rude to commit design documents to github?

Tags: git, github, binaryfiles

As a designer I use git on my local machine to track projects that, in addition to source code, often contain iterations of icons, pdf manuals, slideware, interaction design documents, and even a short how-to video or two that'll be bundled with the software.

I don't know whether git is the right tool for [version control of design artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494082/is-a-vcs-appropriate-for-usage-by-a-designer) or whether I should bite the bullet and move my stuff over to Subversion, Perforce, PlasticSCM, or something designed to handle binary blobs. But the files aren't large and the extra gig it uses on my personal machine to keep them versioned in git is cheaper than the overhead of switching to a different version control system just for my design artifacts. (Though I am trying to figure out if git submodule, git annex, or git bup might help.)

However, my question is whether it would be rude to put one of these projects on github. I'd like to share it with some collaborators and it would be most convenient (for me anyway) to just push the entire repository as is. AFIK github doesn't come out and say that projects should consist of text files, but it does seem to be an implicit assumption. I'm concerned that pushing a project that contains slideware and videos would be a rude misuse of a community resource, but I'm not sure what would constitute a "rude size" (50MB? 500MB? 5GB?) because they don't define [disk space limits](https://github.com/plans). This particular project repo is less than half a gig so perhaps I'm making much ado about nothing.

[Edit: I completely missed the *other*, more helpful github disk quota help page: https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not rude. Lots of people host binary stuff on Github, and there are even [special viewing modes for images](https://github.com/blog/817-behold-image-view-modes).

Answer (score 0):

Meh, just throw it up there. They have a soft limit on space usage. If someone flags it, it will just be removed. No loss. If you are sharing useful stuff, the worst you will be doing is attracting more potentially paying visitors.